# Finding groups of letters, numbers, or symbols

Tags: python, regex

How can I split a string into substrings based on the characters contained in the substrings. For example, given a string `"ABC12345..::"`, I would like to get a list like `['ABC', '12345', '..::']`. I know the valid characters for each substring, but I don't know the lengths. So the string could also look like `"CC123:....:"`, in which case I would like to have `['CC', '123', ':....:']` as the result.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to split in to letters, numbers and symbols?

Comment: Do you have to consider situations like `'ABC123DEF'`?

Comment: Yes, in principle the character set in the three "blocks" can overlap. The middle block can even be empty. So, yes, this causes problems. But for my specific problem, this best-effort approach works reasonable well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your example you don't seem to have anything to split with (e.g. nothing between `C` and `1`), but what you do have is a well-formed pattern that you can match.  So just simply create a pattern that groups the strings you want matched:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ABC12345..::"
>>> re.match('([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)([\.:]*)', s).groups()
('ABC', '12345', '..::')
```

Alternative, compile the pattern into a reusable regex object and do this:

```
>>> patt = re.compile('([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)([\.:]*)')
>>> patt.match(s).groups()
('ABC', '12345', '..::')
>>> patt.match("CC123:....:").groups()
('CC', '123', ':....:')
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I was even close, only forgot the `(...)` brackets around the individual blocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Match each group with the following regex

```
[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[.:]+
```

- `[0-9]+` any digits repeated any times, or
- `[a-zA-Z]+` any letters repeated any times, or
- `[.:]+` any dots or colons repeated any times

This will allow you to match groups in any order, ie: `"123...xy::ab..98765PQRS"`.

---

```
import re
print(re.findall( r'[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[.:]+', "ABC12345..::"))

# => ['ABC', '12345', '..::']
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/jGXPzY)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-`regex` approach:

```
value = 'ABC12345..::'
indexes = [i for i, char in enumerate(value) if char.isdigit()] # Collect indexes of any digits
arr = [ value[:indexes[0]], value[indexes[0]:indexes[-1]+1], value[indexes[-1]+1:] ] # Use splicing to build list
```

Output:

```
['ABC', '12345', '..::']
```

Another string:

```
value = "CC123:....:"
indexes = [i for i, char in enumerate(value) if char.isdigit()] # Collect indexes of any digits
arr = [ value[:indexes[0]], value[indexes[0]:indexes[-1]+1], value[indexes[-1]+1:] ] # Use splicing to build list
```

Output:

```
['CC', '123', ':....:']
```

**EDIT:**

Just did a benchmark, metatoaster's method is slightly faster than this :)